# any aircrack compatable adapters apart from Alfa AWUS036H

Tags: wireless-networking, signal

I am looking for any wi-fi adapters which are compatable with aircrack. I came to know that Alfa AWUS036H is excellent in terms of performance but it has so many issues with regard to drop packets. Is this true? has anyone used it?

Any informatio on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am looking for adapters compatable for packet injection

Comment: The issue you are referring to is not just a drop packet issue.  The injection mode driver on the linux side doesn't handle association properly.  The solution - don't use the same driver for normal traffic and injection.  Alfa cards work for EITHER injection through the ieee stack OR regular use through the 802.11 stack.  Something else to remember is that USB throughput is limited and you have to send control commands and data.  If you are using the right driver for the right thing and you still get high drops, move the usb to a dedicated controller and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend Atheros WLAN controller. I'm using 2 Eee PCs: The 701 4G with an Atheros chipset (AR5BXB63) and it works just fine. On the Eee PC 1000 i replaced the original Ralink controller (which did not support packet injection and monitor mode) with a AR5008.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat true but see I'm using a Windows 7 operating system and it works great.  I think the biggest issue right now that I can find and will always find is cooling.  I put it next to my house fan and it gets double the speed.

On Windows XP it does drop packets but that is because of the software that came with it is balls you have to go online to Alfa's website and get yourself the Windows 7 install.

I bought this product for 30 dollars and its so great.  I pick up my grandparents router from 200 feet away pulling a third of what they get but more ping than they get.  I bridged the connection and it works great with my Xbox no lag on my end sir just dont expect me to be the server :D